# Will 'else' should be used in C++ if there is a return to finish the function

Tags: c++

Just curious about the good practice of writing codes in C++, take the following codes as an example:

```
int do_something()
{ 
   bool bHas;
   ....
   ....
   if (bHas)
   {
     ...
     return 1; 
   }

   ... do something else
   ...
   return 2;


}
```

In the above codes, we can see if `bool bHas` is set true, then the function will be finished in the middle; otherwise it will continue to execute the rest codes. It is also possible to write the above codes in the following way:

```
   int do_something()
    { 
       bool bHas;
       ....
       ....
       if (bHas)
       {
         ...
         return 1; 
       }
       else
       {

       ... do something else
       ...
       return 2;
       }


    }
```

As you can see, this time '`else`' is used to exactly tell what will be done depending on the value of `bool bHas`.  My question here is: which practice is better? thanks.

Comment: The generated code will be identical, so it's up to personal preference. Hence, it's off-topic. (I omit the `else`, because it's introducing another layer of indentation unnecessarily)

Comment: Like the first one better (too many indentations make code less visible)

Answer (score -2):

At a first glance, the second once looks better because of it's uniformity in returns statements. To me, using a single point of return in methods is more preferable. It makes identifying statements, debugging and extending the code easier and less error prone. I would write something like

```
int do_something()
{ 
   bool bHas;
   ....
   ....
   int retValue;
   if (bHas)
   {
     ...
     retValue = 1; 
   }
   else
   {

   ... do something else
   ...
   retValue = 2;
   }

 .....
 return retValue;
}
```

Comment: Do you have evidence that a single return statement produces better code?

Comment: @stefan, did I say anything close to this?

Comment: I tend to agree with you, but I can see exceptions; I'll use multiple returns if the function ends with a `switch` or an `if/else if` chain, and _all_ of the branches clearly end in a `return`.  (This is necessary if the returned type doesn't have a default constructor.)  The important thing is that it be "obvious"; each branch must be extremely short, for example.

Comment: @RakibulHasan No and that's the point. All you state is opinion which doesn't make this a good answer, in my opinion.

Comment: i like to handle it the same way and it has the benefit of `assert`ing the value before returning it

Comment: The problem with this to me is that it's quite easy to miss out a branch in which `retValue` gets set, and thus `return` the default value. I prefer to write my code in a way that will cause the compiler to complain about a missing `return` if I forget a branch, which necessitates the multiple-return style.

Comment: @stefan, correct, the OP asked for opinion. This question can be closed for being opinion based, but it has nothing to do with quality of answer.

Comment: @stefan All of the literature about verifying program correctness is based on the single entry/single exit principle.  I'll use multiple returns in some cases, but only when they can easily be assimilated to a single entry/single exit (i.e. a single branching structure in which every branch leads to a `return`).

Comment: @stefan There are proofs that single point of return produces better code (better = more readable, error prone, etc.). For example book Code Complete is 1.) explaining reasons, 2.) mentioning the proofs.